# Delete the text when clicked - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a code that I can add a list element text and delete it when clicking a certain part in the text, using two functions - add_in() and del_in().
so if I click add button, it should add "Reading (del)"
and when I click the text del, it should delete it.
I looked for getting the id of clicked element here, and used event target.

In add_in(), it adds the list element and I change its content using innerHTML so it contains a p element of (del).
the delNode should start del_in() when clicked.
In del_in(), it has addEventListener to get the id of clicked element and if it's a (del), it deletes.

html

```
<ol id='interests'>
//should be added here.
</ol>
<input type="text" id='add_int'></input>
<input type="button" value="add" id='add_btt' onclick='add_in();'>
```

javascript

```
var idcount = 0;

function add_in() {
    nodeId = "new" + idcount;
    ++idcount;
    var interest = document.getElementById('add_int').value;
    var newNode = document.createElement("li");
    newNode.setAttribute("id", nodeId);
    newNode.innerHTML = interest + "<p id='del" + nodeId + "'>(del)</p>";
    document.getElementById("interests").appendChild(newNode);
    var delNode = document.getElementById('del' + nodeId);
    delNode.setAttribute("onclick", "del_in();");

}

function del_in() {
    var clickId = "";
    document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        clickId = e.target.id;
    });
    if (clickId.includes("delnew")) {
        var clickEle = document.getElementById(clickId);
        clickEle.parentNode.removeChild(clickEle);
    }
}
```

It can add, but can't delete. Nothing happens when clicked.
If I type 'newNode' in console, it says: VM247:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: delNode is not defined. ClickId is not defined either after clicking an element.

Thanks for any help in advance.
Let me know if the code looks too complicated or the question looks too half-assed. I'll edit.

Comment: var delNode = document.getElementById('delnew'+nodeId);

Comment: @Banzay nodeId itself includs new. (nodeId="new"+idcount;)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var idcount = 0;

function add_in() {
    nodeId = "new" + idcount;
    ++idcount;
    var interest = document.getElementById('add_int').value;
    var newNode = document.createElement("li");
    newNode.setAttribute("id", nodeId);
    newNode.innerHTML = interest + "<p id='del" + nodeId + "'>(del)</p>";
    document.getElementById("interests").appendChild(newNode);
    var delNode = document.getElementById('del' + nodeId);
    delNode.setAttribute("onclick", "del_in(this);");

}

function del_in(e) {    
    e.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```html
<ol id='interests'>
//should be added here.
</ol>
<input type="text" id='add_int'></input>
<input type="button" value="add" id='add_btt' onclick='add_in();'>
```

the easy and simplest way you can try select parent element and change it e.parentNode.remove();